# JSF PhaseListener called not at all or twice

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3

I have a PhaseListener, which seems to work correctly mostly => called mostly when expected and does what expected, but it is not called at all when the application is entered for the first time and in turn called twice on every call when once in the application (e.g. refresh).

The phaseId is: PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;

MyListener has:

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) { /* stuff */ }

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent arg0) { /* Nothing done here */ }
```

I can see with debug-breakpoint that the 'beforePhase' is called twice when the page is refreshed (or page switched), but it's not called at all when the user is directed to this application from a link for example.

In faces-config.xml I have:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.package.project.MyListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

I am using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces 3.5.

Comment: Occurred to my mind. The page has includes and a dialog. May they cause the PhaseListener to be called twice?

Comment: Ok, this is crazy. I added 'if (event.getPhaseId() == this.getPhaseId()) { /* stuff */ }' in beforePhase and suddenly it stopped calling the method twice (and no, putting break point on the 'if' I can see it is called only once). But still it is not invoked at all when entering the application for the first time???

Comment: While debugging, look in the call stack who called it.

Comment: Ok. There are a lot of threads running simultaneously. On separate times it seems to be randomly any of the threads named: 'http-thread-pool-8080(1-5)'. When it is caught twice per request, it is always two different threads (the pair changes every time). I noticed there is a difference between a page refresh (ctrl+R) and selecting a tab. On page refresh the PhaseListener is called only once, on tab selection it is called twice (the tab contents are in included files).

Comment: Perhaps you're using an iframe instead of include?

Comment: <ui:include src="fragments/tabXX.xhtml"></ui:include>. So no. That could had explained it, but ...

Comment: I can actually have a workaround for this, to prevent duplicate processing on tab change, but it still leaves a mystery why the PhaseListener is not called on entering the page the first time. The application is always entered via an outside service, could that have an effect with this? => A Filter redirects the user for SSO login, then after login, user is returned to the main page (PhaseListener not called)